# Laravel - export to csv return blank list

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make custom in my laravel project a button to export list of customers...
The route is ok, blade file is ok, the csv is exported but without users details, last_name, first_name and email...

Somebody know why? I am beginner in laravel

```
     public function exportCsv(Request $request) {
   $fileName = 'tasks.csv';
    $users = User::role('staff');
        $headers = array(
            "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
            "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires"             => "0"
        );

        $columns = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

        $callback = function() use($users, $columns) {
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $row['first_name']  = $user->first_name;
                $row['last_name']    = $user->last_name;
                $row['email']    = $user->email;

                fputcsv($file, array($row['first_name'], $row['last_name'], $row['email']));
            }

            fclose($file);
        };

        return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, please edit your question, and format your code properly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks A Stack Snippet is for client-side code, that can be run directly in the viewer’s browser - so it makes no sense for your server-side code here to begin with.

Comment: Did you verify these properties you are trying to access are actually filled in $users (resp. the single $user, within the foreach loop)?

Comment: Yes, in our db we have over 200 results without roles             $users = User::doesntHave('roles');

Comment: I did not ask what you have in your database, I asked you to _verify_ what the variables inside your script actually contain.

Comment: I don't know how to do that... I tried to modify first_name with id, which is called and works in another functions, but there is not exported..

Comment: Well normally you would just use `var_dump` or something to dump the content of a variable, and check for the result in your page output in the frontend … But since you are doing a download here, that might not work so well. Try and remove all the headers (which cause the result to be offered for download), put a var_dump inside the loop, and see what that results in.